# How can I save a text written in TexMaker as as a .bib-file?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texmaker

I want to create an external bibliography using BibTex. I am using TexMaker for the text, but do not know how to save the text as an .bib-file. Does anybody know how to do so?

Comment: Have you tried File -> Save As ?

Comment: Save As, and add yourself the extension. However I would suggest using JabRef to create.bib files: you only have to fill forms, and it will detect syntax errors.

Comment: You can copy a file bib from your friend, after then delete contain and insert your contain to instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, when you save it, you had the good extension (.bib). After, it will be correctly recognize.
--> you create your new document in texmaker, file menu, save as, and here, as name, you put fo example 'biblio.bib".
You can also create a text file, rename the extension (or directly save/create it as biblio.bib). After, it will be treat as a bibtex file by you favorite editor.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the bib file is created by yourself. And you can easily copy the bib style from Google Scholar.

Click the **cite** label under the paper.
[image]

Then Click the *BibTex*.
[image]

And copy the BibTex style to your bib file.

Comment: And remember to check if the downloaded stuff is correct.